# Derivation of Klein disc metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In Weinberg's textbook on gravitation and cosmology he describes very early on the Klein disc model, giving the equation for the distance in the model: for two points $x = (x_1,x_2)$ and $X = (X_1,X_2)$ the distance between these two points is given by $d(x,X)$ where

$$\cosh \frac{d(x,X)}{a} = \frac{1-x \cdot X}{\sqrt{1 - x \cdot x} \sqrt{1 - X \cdot X} }$$

and

$$x \cdot X = x_1 * X_1 + x_2 * X_2.$$

He then a few pages in finds the metric components to be

$$g_{11} = a^2 \frac{(1-x_2^2)}{(1-x_1^2 - x_2^2)^2}, \quad g_{12} = a^2 \frac{x_1x_2}{(1-x_1^2 - x_2^2)^2}, \quad g_{22} = a^2 \frac{(1-x_1^2)}{(1-x_1^2 - x_2^2)^2}.$$

I have no clue how he manages to do this, given no direct coordinate transformation. I've tried reverse engineering this by just plugging in the metric components to the distance equation, but the hyperbolic cosine is messing me up. Can someone explain how he obtains this result?